# Change Paper Size

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, crystal-reports

How to Change Paper Size of a print dialog programatically C#?

I Want to Change the paper size to a user-defined paper size for Eg: *10x12* is my `Paper Size`.

It is much better if you help me in how to print in Crystal Report with the paper size *10x12*.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer This Page for Answer :

[Answer for Paper Size](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9e647fac-d5cd-42b7-a1e6-db6d6cf97c57/setting-pagesize-for-crystal-report?forum=vscrystalreports)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways of changing the papaer size. Keep in mind that the printer has to be able to handel the paper size you specify!

We can set the print options by using the PrintOptions class.  We should get
the PrintOptions with the report so that we only have to set the properties that we are changing.

```
PrintOptions boPrintOptions = boReportClientDocument.PrintOutputController.GetPrintOptions();

        boPrintOptions.DissociatePageSizeAndPrinterPaperSize = false;
        boPrintOptions.DriverName = "my printer driver name";
        boPrintOptions.PageContentHeight = 11;
        boPrintOptions.PageContentWidth = 8;

        PageMargins boPageMargins = new PageMargins();
        boPageMargins.Bottom = 1;
        boPageMargins.Top = 1;
        boPageMargins.Left = 1;
        boPageMargins.Right = 1;

        boPrintOptions.PageMargins = boPageMargins;
        boPrintOptions.PaperOrientation = CrPaperOrientationEnum.crPaperOrientationDefault;
        boPrintOptions.PaperSize = CrPaperSizeEnum.crPaperSizeDefault;
        boPrintOptions.PaperSource = CrPaperSourceEnum.crPaperSourceAuto;
        boPrintOptions.PortName = "";
        boPrintOptions.PrinterDuplex = CrPrinterDuplexEnum.crPrinterDuplexDefault;
        boPrintOptions.PrinterName = @"\\van-s-prt01\VAN-P-OLYMPIA";
```

Once we set the PrintOptions that we want we need to use the modify method to apply these settings. These values are not validated so we may get an exception thrown when we try to print.

```
boReportClientDocument.PrintOutputController.ModifyPrintOptions(boPrintOptions);
```

Our other option for changing the print options is to use the Modify methods that are available.  These are nicer to use as we do not have to get the previous values, set the ones that we want then use the previous modify method, we can directly set the properties that we want to change. These measurements are in twips.  1440 twips per inch. When using the Modify methods below, the values are validate and will throw an exception if the value is not acceptable, or the new printer name is not available. This line sets the papersize 11 inches tall, 8 inches wide:

```
        boReportClientDocument.PrintOutputController.ModifyUserPaperSize((11 * 1440), (8 * 1440));
        boReportClientDocument.PrintOutputController.ModifyPageMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
        boReportClientDocument.PrintOutputController.ModifyPaperOrientation(CrPaperOrientationEnum.crPaperOrientationLandscape);
        boReportClientDocument.PrintOutputController.ModifyPrinterName(@"\\van-s-prt01\VAN-P-OLYMPIA");

        //Print the report.
        boReportClientDocument.PrintOutputController.PrintReport(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
CRAXDRT.Report report1 = new CRAXDRT.Report();
CRAXDRT.Application app1 = new CRAXDRT.Application();
report1 = app1.OpenReport(@"F:\YourReport.rpt", OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByDefault);
report1.PaperSize = CRPaperSize.crPaper10x14;
```

Comment: I Know to set the paper size to pre defined paper sizes bt i wan to set it to user defined paper size help me out